# How to stop running the application if signed code is tampered with

Tags: code-signing, xcodebuild

We are writing plugin and bundle. As part of security measure we are planning to sign the code. Issue that we are facing is we have successfully signed the plugin and bundle. When i am running this plugin and bundle those are running without any issue. 
 Now i have modified its content by updating one of the file in bundle and verified from terminal its giving below message

code or signature modified

but still its running without any issue. Now the question how can i make sure that code modified after signing it should fail to load ?  i have read the documentation but no place this is explained. Who verifies code signature in client machine and stop loading if its fails verification.
Please advice